# Graphics2D in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Firstly, sorry for this type of question.
I´m learning `Java` programming, I have quite a lot skills in this language, but until now I haven´t used graphics2D. I want to learn how to create graphics, but I haven´t found any helpful tutorial. Please, do you know some good tutorial about learning how to create graphics? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about [the tutorial by Oracle?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: and rest of methods  [example by example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm) notice most of methods are invoked from `paint()` instead of `paintComponent()`,

Comment: google anyone? are you looking for something like Swing?

Comment: Another good link http://www.cs.xu.edu/~fowee/csci380/report2/graphics2d.html.

Comment: @mKorbel, that´s exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends by what you mean by Graphics2D.  This covers a large area, from painting custom components to painting games and/or animation

I'd start with something like [2D Graphics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

I'd make sure your familiar with [Custom Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

I'd also make myself familiar with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Once that begins to make scene, you'd take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) because eventually you want to use `Threads`.  Pay close attention to the Event Dispatching Thread topic

Answer (score 2):

**[Java How To Program 9/e (early objects)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132575663)** has some very nice introduction to Java's graphics.

At each chapter there is a **Case Study** where you are introduced to different graphics java features and also there are exercises which are very challenging.

Then, later there is the **Graphics and Java 2D** chapter (chapter 15) where there is a very nice cover of Java's 2D graphics.

Then if you want to go deeper into Java's 2D Graphics, you can browse through the [Java 2D API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec.html)

Comment: what is Java How To Program 9/e? care to share a link?